# Customize "Sum" label on addmargins function

Tags: r, function, customization, margins

Let the following table:

```
x <- sample(1:2, 100, replace = T)
tabela <- table(x)
```

To which I add margins

```
> addmargins(tabela)
x
  1   2 Sum 
 51  49 100
```

However, I would like to change the "Sum" label to "Total". How do I do this?

My current workaround is to run `addmargins` to get the function's source code, copy it to my script and change the string `"Sum"` to `"Total"`, but I imagine there is a cleverer way to accomplish this.

Comment: You could also change `attr(t1, "dimnames")$x[3] <- "Suma"` if `t1 <- addmargins(tabela)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick look at `addmargin`'s source code will show that, when it's explicitly passed a function via it's `FUN=` argument, it names the marginal column by deparsing the supplied function's name.

A quick solution, then, is to pass in a function that sums the elements but has the name that you'd like to have printed there.

```
Total <- sum
addmargins(tabela, FUN = Total)
# x
#     1     2 Total 
#    49    51   100
```